# How to stream XML from SQL Server 2005 to HTTP Response stream for download

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 that generates a 170 megabyte XML file (using `SELECT FOR XML`)

How, in ASP.NET, would I stream this XML for download as a file in a web browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this has been working for me for a while.  Note you'll have to tailor it to your situation:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {
    // your settings
};

using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(response.Output, settings))
using (var connection = YourConnection())
using (var command = CreateCommand(sql, connection, dbParams) as SqlCommand )
{
    try {
        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteXmlReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
                xmlWriter.WriteNode(reader, true);
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        // log, whatever
        throw;
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to make response download, you'll have to set the HTTP headers, something like [this](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/21/Downloading-a-File-with-a-Save-As-Dialog-in-ASPNET).  That's really a separate question.

I agree with @Metropolitan that your output size is suspiciously large for a web download.  I'm just trying to answer the question as asked, but you're probably going to have to reconsider the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Harpo's answer is good but you need to prep your Response to make it work in ASP.NET. Create a page, you can call it "Download.aspx". Then in the Page_load, you need to stream the contents.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();

            if (Request.QueryString["key"] != null)
            {
                Response.AppendHeader("content", contentType);
                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=something.xml");
                Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

                // Here you would call your sproc (see harpo's answer)
                // and write to Response.Output
            }
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle your errors
        }
    }
```

Comment: I only do this kind of thing from an `IHttpHandler`, so the clear methods are not needed.  But good point.

Answer (score -1):

[I am pretty sure you need to write some SQL SERVER DLL that will ZIP that XML file and save it locally.](http://www32.brinkster.com/srisamp/sqlArticles/article_33.htm)

After this it should insert some row in some table that this file is ready.

[Perhaps you have to add WCF service into you ASP .NET project that will be able to stream that ZIP file.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP)

Something like this...

Anyway 170 Mb XML hmmmm Sounds like you have to review many things to reduce output size...